# Recycler View background image gets shrink when keyboard popups through editText

Tags: android, recyclerview-layout

I have a recycler-view with a sample background in my activity but I'm stuck in an error. Whenever keyboard popups in the activity, the background of recycler-view gets shrink. How to avoid this thing. Means how to stop it from being shrinking ? Here are the images attached below.

[normal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaJoE.png)

[shrinked background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14ctI.png)

XML Code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:hint="Your text here"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code..

Comment: There is no specific code. Just a recycler view and an editText in layout xml.

Comment: @AhsanArif try this **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`**

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried that. In this case, background doesn't shrink but the editText stays behind keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In the  tag of the recyclerview container activity declared in manifest add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
```

like

```
 <activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing" />
```

Comment: I tried that. In this case, background doesn't shrink but the editText stays behind keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

add the image to your background of layout, not in recyclerview. And also recyclerview's item should have no background color except its necessary to widgets.

Comment: Tried it too. Still the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode` to be `"adjustPan"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under your `activity`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: Can you at least split what is code and what is not in your answer?